# How to remove empty rows in data of 'Object of Array' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an Object of arrays.And its output looks like this. [Object of array output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAkZ0.png)

[image]

And code is like this

```
layer.fields.each(function(field) {
tr.append($('<th ></th>').text(field.name));
if(self.availableForTable.indexOf(field.name.toUpperCase()) != -1)
self.tblHeader.push(field.name);
});
tbody.append(tr);`
```

Now the issue is that I got some entries empty from database. like this  [like after 1 line 2nd line is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qufi1.png).

[image]

Now how to remove this empty space. Is there any way in javascript for "Object of Array"?I searched on StackOverflow but didn't get any useful thing so far

Comment: Post your ouput data as well..

Comment: both images are output @Ved

Comment: `layer = layer.filter(function(entry) { return /\S/.test(entry); });` will remove white spaces from array

Comment: Image you shared is `Array of arrays`.

Comment: what do you mean by 'Object of array output'?

Comment: @Ved I checked type by 'Typeof myarray' its giving Object.

Comment: @Khaleel a Object containing arrays.

Comment: @F128115 the screenshot is array of arrays. anyways logically. before appending the tr check `if(field.name != "" || field.name != null)`

Comment: @AlivetoDie  worked like a charm :D . kindly post as answer I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove white spaces from array do like below:-

```
layer = layer.filter(function(entry) { return /\S/.test(entry); });
```

Comment: @F128115  glad to help you :):)

Comment: Can I ask a little more ? In 2nd case I have a Object containing objects. Now what I have to do to remove empty objects ?

Comment: @F128115  please check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/42736367/4248328

Comment: on both ways I getting undefined

Comment: @F128115   ask a new question with some input data and what you tried ? you will get answer for-sure

Comment: l already did but still no one gave valid answer . Kindly check if you could help . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865041/remove-object-from-object-of-objects