# Remove Object from "Object of Objects"

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a Object that contain objetcs like this.`Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "P O BOX 59", APN: "066-102-11-1"}` . Now I need data without empty Object. Like I get output like this **Output**

```
Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "P O BOX 59", APN: "066-102-11-1"}
Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "", APN: ""}
Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "P O BOX 3", APN: "066-105-11-1"}
Object {MAILING ADDRESS: "", APN: ""}
```

So in this case I dont want to get 2nd and 4th object. And in case of 100 I dont want to get 2,4,6,8..100 index . Because output after one time is repeating and I have to remove this.  [ScreenShot of output I getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJCmk.png)

```
//Code How I am creating this
ExportTool.prototype.click = function(value) {
  var lidtest = mapport.panels.info.current.selection.features.mem;

  if (value != undefined) {
    var lid = lidtest[value].attributes.layer_id;
  } else {
    var lid = lidtest[0].attributes.layer_id;
  }

  if (!lid) return;
  var tbody;
  var thead;
  tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>');
  thead = $('<thead></thead>');
  self = this;

  // Reset
  this.tblHeader = [];
  this.tblData = [];
  this.labelData = [];

  // thead.children().remove();
  // tbody.children().remove();
  //var tbody;

  var layer = mapport.layer(lid);
  var tr = $('<tr></tr>');

  layer.fields.each(function(field) {
    tr.append($('<th ></th>').text(field.name));
    // Table heading for the PDF
    if (self.availableForTable.indexOf(field.name.toUpperCase()) != -1)
      self.tblHeader.push(field.name);
  });

  tbody.append(tr);

  var features = mapport.panels.info.current.features();
  for (var i = 0; i < features.length; ++i) {
    if (features[i].geometry != null) {
      var data = features[i].attributes.data,
        row_data = [],
        row_field, obj_field = {};

      tr = $('<tr></tr>');

      layer.fields.each(function(field) {
        var field_name = field.name.toUpperCase();
        var td = $('<td></td>');
        if (data[field.id] != null) td.text(data[field.id]);
        tr.append(td);

        if (self.availableForTable.indexOf(field_name) != -1) {
          row_field = (data[field.id] != null) ? data[field.id] : '';
          row_data.push(row_field);
          obj_field[field_name] = row_field;
        }
      });

      row_data = row_data.filter(function(entry) {
        return /\S/.test(entry);
      });

      obj_field = JSON.parse(obj_field);
      console.log(obj_field);
      // Table Data for the PDF
      this.tblData.push(row_data);
      // Table Data for the PDF
      this.labelData.push(obj_field);
      tbody.append(tr);
      $('#table_multi_layers').append(tbody);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the full data structure. This looks more like an array of objects.

Comment: Is this an array of objects?

Comment: How does you base object contain these objects, are they in an array (`{addresses:[{...},{...}]}`) or are the properties of the object (`{address1:{...},address2:{...}}`)?

Comment: it looks like you are logging lot of objects. make it an array and then filter them

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  creating like this  obj_field = {};. This result which I showed is  console.log(obj_field );

Comment: How are the objects you've shown above being added to that object? You must give them keys at some point

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I posted code . I consoled obj_field

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I tried Filter but It giving uncaught error. You have any solution ?

Comment: You should probably filter first, and create a table after it. How to filter: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/37ckxbrk/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Its very larger project. I posted now full function kindly check.

Comment: @wostex No method to apply on a object ?

Comment: @noor in order to avoid all these of comments just show the structure which you want to filter, which everyone can work with instead of trying to guess it.

Comment: @wostex I posted full code. I just want to filter obj_field result before pushing it into  this.labelData at the end of function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter option like this. You can change your object to array and apply filter.

```
var someArray = $.map(obj_field, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
```

```js
someArray = [{
    MAILINGADDRESS: "P O BOX 59",
    APN: "066-102-11-1"
  },
  {
    MAILINGADDRESS: "",
    APN: ""
  },
  {
    MAILINGADDRESS: "P O BOX 59",
    APN: "066-102-11-1"
  }, {
    MAILINGADDRESS: "",
    APN: ""
  }
];
result = someArray.filter(function(el) {
  return el.APN !== "";
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, ' '));
```

Comment: obj_field.filter is not a function   that error I get . Because its not array  @Shree

Comment: what is obj_field ??

Comment: is of Object type that contain objects. You can see output snapshot which I have attached , And it is result of console.log(obj_field);