# How to improve method for cleaning nested object to remove empty objects as well

Tags: javascript, nested

Need to improve method for cleaning nested object to remove empty objects as well

```js
const sanitizeNestedObject = obj => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, value) => {
    if (value === null || value === "" || value === [] || value === {}) return undefined
    return value
})
```

output after cleaning

```
{"expressions":[{
"hasSchemaTag":{"schemaTag":"Hardware"}},
{"hasAttribute":{"attribute":"serialNumber"}},{},{},
{"hasAnySchemaTags":{"schemaTags":["UCSFanModule","UCSMemoryArray"]}},{},{}
]}
```

expected output after cleaning

```
{"expressions":[{
"hasSchemaTag":{"schemaTag":"Hardware"}},
{"hasAttribute":{"attribute":"serialNumber"}},
{"hasAnySchemaTags":{"schemaTags":["UCSFanModule","UCSMemoryArray"]}}
]}
```

Comment: Never compare against object literals, these checks are destined to fail, as JS compares objects by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if the object has keys (that will cover arrays and objects). And if not, trim out:

```
const sanitizeNestedObject = obj => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, value) => {
  if (value === null || value === "" || (typeof value === 'object' && !Object.keys(value).length)) return undefined
  return value
})
```

You could of course shorten the function to this:

```
const sanitizeNestedObject = obj => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, value) => {
  return (value === null || value === "" || (typeof value === 'object' && !Object.keys(value).length) ? undefined : value)
})
```

Result:

```
{"expressions":[{"hasSchemaTag":{"schemaTag":"Hardware"}},{"hasAttribute":{"attribute":"serialNumber"}},{"hasAnySchemaTags":{"schemaTags":["UCSFanModule","UCSMemoryArray"]}}]}
```

To be safe, I checked with other values too:

This (note the numbers, strings and empty arrays):

```
{"expressions":[{"hasSchemaTag":{"schemaTag":"Hardware"}},{"hasAttribute":{"attribute":"serialNumber"}},{},{},[],[],["a","b","",18,0],{"hasAnySchemaTags":{"schemaTags":["UCSFanModule","UCSMemoryArray"]}},{},{}]}
```

Gets into this:

```
{"expressions":[{"hasSchemaTag":{"schemaTag":"Hardware"}},{"hasAttribute":{"attribute":"serialNumber"}},["a","b",18,0],{"hasAnySchemaTags":{"schemaTags":["UCSFanModule","UCSMemoryArray"]}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the answers to [Remove empty objects from an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736031/remove-empty-objects-from-an-object) on `obj` before throwing it into `JSON.stringify()`. Be aware of mutating the object!